# How to cut time zone information in Java

Tags: java, date

This is my Data `2018-07-03 00:00:00+02` but I want to get this `2018-07-03`.
How is possible to cut hor, minutes, seconds and time zone in Java?

Comment: What data type is this? `String`, `Date`?

Comment: My data type is `Data`. And I just want `2018-07-03`.

Comment: what is the expected result 2018-07-03 or  00:00:00+02

Comment: Which `Data` class is that? It’s not one I know. (I only know at least two classes called `Date` with an `e`, both poorly designed and both long outdated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateTimeFormatter.

```
  LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String text = date.format(formatter);
```

If you are using Java 8 it is better to use `java.time.LocalDate`. If you have to use `java.util.Date` you can still convert it to `LocalDate`.

```
Date now= new Date();
LocalDate date = now.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your input to a `ZoneDateTime` and then extract the `LocalDate` from it like so :

```
String str = "2018-07-03 00:00:00+02".replace(" ", "T"); 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str);
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate(); // 2018-07-03
```

Note: I used replace space with `'T'` to respect the default format of `ZonedDateTime`.

---

Or much better, you can use `OffsetDateTime` instead of `ZonedDateTime` as suggested by [`Ole V.V.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784711/how-to-cut-time-zone-information-in-java/59785067#comment105713852_59784794)

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

For a datetime `String` that contains an offset, I would use an `OffsetDateTime` in order to parse it and then format it with a `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` which just prints the date part.

You have to provide a specific pattern to the `DateTimeFormatter` used for parsing the `String` because the `String` is not in a standardized format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String datetime = "2018-07-03 00:00:00+02";
    // parse it with a specific pattern
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(datetime, 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX"));
    // print it using a built-in standardized pattern FOR THE DATE PART ONLY
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```

The output is `2018-07-03`

This way, you don't have to manipulate the `String` before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the Java Date class, you can extract different parts of the Date/Time using different methods belonging to the class. 
If d represents your date object, `d.getYear()` will get the year, `d.getTime()` gets the time and so on. 

You can use the DateTimeFormatter if this is a String.

```
DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");  
String formatDateTime = currentDateTime.format(format1);   
System.out.println(formatDateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
String strDate= formatter.format(date);
```

Try this, pass your date object in formatter.format(date);

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.